# Magento 1.9 redirect catalog/product/view/id/123 URL to product-url Key

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

In Magento 1.9 I was facing this issue on all the product listing pages as the links generated were like (`catalog/product/view/id/123`), which I have managed to change to product url by setting "**Use Web Server Rewrites**" to yes.

But now I need if someone enters the url (`catalog/product/view/id/123`) then it should also be redirected to (`product-name.html`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by creating an observer for event `http_response_send_before`

Following is the code in observer:

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if (strpos($currentUrl, 'catalog/product/view/id') !== false) {
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    $seo_url = Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($params['id'], 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($seo_url);
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for others.